# What is the purpose of this module?

Tags: verilog, bluespec

```
module InoutConnect(
                .X1(internal), 
                .X2(internal)
                );


   parameter width = 1;

   inout [ width - 1 : 0 ] internal;
endmodule // InoutConnect
```

In the above code what is the format used,
I know that while instantiating the module .x1 is use to match the variable name but what about module definition.
What does it mean here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is called `explicit port declaration`, meaning that the external world will know this port by its explicit names, **X1** and **X2** in your case, though internally the same port will be known as **internal** in your case.

So, in your example you connect both ports to the same internal variable (looks bad to me :)) Though, this is one of the possible uses, in particular if you need to identical output ports. The other example is remapping internal structs or arrays to multiple potrts:

```
module m(
   output .arr1(array[2:0]),
   output .arr2(array[7:3]),
   input logic [7:0] input_array
)
   logic [7:0] array;
   ...
   always_ff @(posedge clk)
       array <= input_array;
   ...
endmodule
```

So, above you can use your array as the whole internally, but it will have a different representation in the external world.

See `23.2.2.2 ANSI style list of port declarations` for more info.

Comment: if I wanted to connect the incoming signals using wand but not inout, could it be done in a similar way or some other way?

Comment: `inout` is a **direction** of a port. `wand` is a **type** of a net with a specific resolution algorithm for multiply driven state. So, you cannot replace an apple with a chair. By default the type of the port is **wire** (which is yet another type).

Answer (score 0):

The InoutConnect module is used to create an *alias* between two different signal names. For example

```
wire [7:0] color;
wire [7:0] colour; 
InoutConnect #7 a1(color,colour);
```

Now, color and colour are two names for the same signal.

SystemVerilog added the `alias` construct to do the same thing without needed to create a separate module.

Comment: if I wanted to connect the incoming signals using wand but not inout, could it be done in a similar way or some other way?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Probably needs a separate question.